# RouteEnhancer for TYPO3 v9 indexed_search

Tags: typo3, url-routing, typo3-9.x

I want to rewrite the URL for search result from indexed_search but it's not working. Nothing happen. 
I've added following RouteEnhancer to my config.yaml

```
routeEnhancers:
  IndexedSearchPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages:
      - 38
    extension: IndexedSearch
    plugin: Pi2
    routes:
      - routePath: '/page/{page}'
        _controller: 'Search::search'
        _arguments:
          page: '@widget_0/currentPage'
    defaultController: 'Search::search'
    defaults:
      page: '0'
    requirements:
      page: \d+
    aspects:
      page:
        type: StaticRangeMapper
        start: '1'
        end: '100'
```

Maybe somebody have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use index_search a lot, but had a quick look at the code for the page browser. The page browser for indexed_search is done using a form and JavaScript, not direct links. So when clicking on a page in the page browser a hidden field is set and the form is submitted. Route enhancers will only work for links generated by TYPO3. I'm not sure why this is done this way, but without changing the way the page browser works you can't enhance these URLs.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on what you are trying to beautify. In my case I use this `config.yaml` to get a clean url for the search results (the search field is generated by TypoScript) and be able to search by a query.

Let's say we're having a page `https:example.de/search/` with the indexed_search plugin placed on it.

Now searching from any page with the search field will result in this uri:
`https:example.de/search/results`

And you can deeplink to a special search result (here we're looking for 'lorem') by simply using that uri:
`https:example.de/search/query/lorem`

```
routeEnhancers:
  IndexedSearchPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    namespace: tx_indexedsearch_pi2
    routes:
      - routePath: '/results'
        _controller: 'Search::search'
        _action: 'search::search'
      - routePath: '/query/{search/sword}'
        _controller: 'Search::search'
        _action: 'search::search'
        requirements:
          - search/sword: '[^/=?]*'
    defaultController: 'Search::search'
    defaultAction: 'search::search'
```

At least this did work for me in TYPO3 v10.4.8 (without testing pagination or advanced search).

Comment: If anyone knows how to union these two routes and add the post value to the uri feel free to leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Rudy Gnodde is right: There is no 'page' parameter, so you don't need to configure it.

Just use following routeEnhancer to have an URL like www.domain.com/my-search-page/search where my-search-page is the page holding the indexed_search plugin.

```
routeEnhancers:
  IndexedSearchPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    extension: IndexedSearch
    plugin: Pi2
    routes:
      - routePath: '/search'
        _controller: 'Search::search'
    defaultController: 'Search::search'
```